# Swift - I have same data after tapping a cell using table view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I have a table view in my restaurant app I'm making. I'm struggling with a problem.I have more restaurants in my app, and I want for every restaurant to display different food, but when I'm selecting any restaurant, I have the same data every where.

I'll show my code for the first Table View.

This is where I'm declaring the variables (a struct) which I'm using

```
struct Category {
    let title: String
    let photoKeyHome: String
}
var datas: [Category] = []

var filteredData: [Category]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    filteredData = datas
}
```

This is where I'm retrieving data from my Firestore (I'm using Firestore and firebase storage).

```
func getDatabaseRecords() {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    //  Empty the array
    filteredData = []
    
    db.collection("HomeTableViewRestuarants").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
            return
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let newEntry = Category(
                    title: data["title"] as! String,
                    photoKeyHome: data["photoKeyHome"] as! String
                    
                ) 
                
                self.filteredData
                    .append(newEntry)
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.datas = self.filteredData
            self.homeTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This is my table view and how I'm moving to the second table view where I have the food.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = homeTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "homeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! homeTableViewCell
    let restaurant = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
    let photoRef = storageRef.child(restaurant.photoKeyHome)
    cell.myLabel.text = restaurant.title
    cell.myImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
    
    cell.myView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myView.frame.height / 5
    cell.myImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myImage.frame.height / 5
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    homeTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let vc = RestaurantViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

This is how im retrieving data from my second table view (RestaurantViewController)

```
func getDatabaseRecords() {
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
           //  Empty the array
          food = []
            
            db.collection("RestaurantViewController").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                    return
                } else {
                    for document in snapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let newEntry = Food(photoKeyRestaurant: data["photoKeyRestaurant"] as! String, foodName: data["foodName"] as! String, foodDescription: data["foodDescription"] as! String
                          
                              
                         
                        )
                        print("document is \(document)")
                            
                            
                            
                        self.food.append(newEntry)
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 //  self.datas = self.filteredData
                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

This is my struct:

```
struct Food {
    
    var photoKeyRestaurant: String
    var foodName: String
    var foodDescription: String
}

 var food: [Food] = []
```

And this is my table view for the restaurant view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return food.count
      
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FoodTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FoodTableViewCell
        let mancare = food[indexPath.row]
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        let photoRef = storageRef.child(mancare.photoKeyRestaurant)
        cell.foodImage.sd_setImage(with: photoRef)
        cell.descriptionLabel.text = mancare.foodDescription
        cell.foodNameLabel.text = mancare.foodName
return cell
}
```

For each restaurant, how can I have different food ?

| First table view with restaurants | Second table view with foods |
| --- | --- |
| [image: First table view with restaurants] | [image: Second table view with foods] |

[HomeTableViewRestaurants collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lFZ2.png)
[RestaurantViewController collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3LnV.png)

Comment: You never give the Second view controller the information about the selected restaurant.

Comment: @PtitXav ok, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    homeTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    let restaurant = filteredData[indexPath.row]
    let vc = RestaurantViewController()
    vc.getDatabaseRecords(forRestaurant: restaurant)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

and in second view controller :

```
func getDatabaseRecords(forRestaurant restaurant : Category) {
        
    food = []
    // Here get the data corresponding to restaurant parameter
    ...
    }
```

No need to reload tableview as it will done when the table view will appear

Comment: I've got an error to this line vc.getDatabaseRecords(forRestaurant: restaurant) . ERROR : " Argument passed to call that takes no arguments"

Comment: You can try to rename getDatabaseRecords to something like updateForRestaurant(_ restaurant : Category) in both first and second vc .